# To make a table of contents for many .odt -files

Tags: pdf, openoffice

I have about one hundred files in Open Office's .odt -format such that

```
1 chapter
2 chapter
...
100 chapter
```

I would like **to make a table of contents for these files.** 
However, the problem is that each chapter is in a separate file.

I finally need to convert these files to pdf. It would like **to know how you can convert the 100 files + table of contents to a single file efficiently**. I have done that at the moment by Converting the files first to pdf in OO and then binding the files in Adobe Pro. However, this procedure is very time-consiming.

**How can you make a table of contents of the hundred .odt -files**?

Comment: Please, add tags for open-office and pdf.

Comment: I opened a new thread about applying Monaco -font to all headers in my master document at http://superuser.com/questions/10674/to-apply-monaco-font-to-all-header1s-in-a-master-document-in-oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [master document](http://documentation.openoffice.org/manuals/oooauthors2/0213WG-WorkingWithMasterDocuments.pdf) (PDF), then you can create a comprehensive [table of contents](http://documentation.openoffice.org/manuals/userguide3/0212WG3-TablesOfContentsIndexesBibliographies.pdf) (PDF). You should be able to convert the master document to PDF and have it bring all the sub-documents along with it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! @ I have no headers in my files. The headers should be my filenames. **Is there any way to make a Table of Contents based on filenames only?**

Comment: You might try to see if making your headings using a filename field would work. See Chapter 14 - Working with Fields: http://documentation.openoffice.org/manuals/userguide3/0214WG3-WorkingWithFields.pdf