# To apply Monaco -font to all header_1s in a master document in OO

Tags: openoffice

This question is based on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/10020/to-make-a-table-of-contents-for-many-odt-files).

I would like to apply Monaco -font to all header_1s in a master document in Open Office 3.

I have tried to change the `Header 1` in `Styles and Formatting` unsuccessfully: I change the font to Monace and click ok, and then update 'All` in my master document, but the monaco font does not apply.

**How can you apply Monaco -font to each heading in the master document?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the text that is styled `Header 1` in the master document and the subdocuments to have the same style and to be updated together when you make a change, you need to make the change in the template. Changes that you make in the master document only apply to it.

See Page 10, Step 2 in [Chapter 13 - Working with Master Documents](http://documentation.openoffice.org/manuals/userguide3/0213WG3-WorkingWithMasterDocuments.pdf) and also [Chapter 10 - Working with Templates](http://documentation.openoffice.org/manuals/userguide3/0210WG3-WorkingWithTemplatesInWriter.pdf).

Comment: My "Save" -link at "File > Templates > Save" is not active for some reason: http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/template-oo.png --- Do you know why the link is not active?

Comment: On my Ubuntu system, OOo Writer has the File>Template>Save menu item grayed out for master documents but not regular ones.

Answer (score 1):

After setting up the pages, or before, edit the Styles and Formatting

(Menu > Format > Styles and Formatting *or* <kbd>F11</kbd> ).

1. Right-click **Heading 1** and select **Modify...**
2. Select the ***Font*** tab
3. Select the font type, size and style as required
4. Click OK

If it works, all **`Heading 1`** elements of the document should update to the newly selected font style.

Comment: @echo: I agree with you. --- About 80% of my `Heading 1` changes correctly, but 20% remains untouched: http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/headings-oo.png

Comment: Are the unaffected headings completely styled as Heading 1 and don't have some other style applied to the middle of the word?