# To have a pagebreak in each before each subdocument in OO's master document

Tags: openoffice

This question is based on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/10674/to-apply-monaco-font-to-all-header1s-in-a-master-document-in-oo).

I would like to have all my sub-essays in own page by having a pagebreak before each `Heading 1`.

**How can you put a pagebreak before each `Heading 1` in a master document in Open Office 3?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting up the pages, or before, edit the Styles and Formatting

(Menu > Format > Styles and Formatting *or* <kbd>F11</kbd> ).

1. Right-click **Heading 1** and select **Modify...**
2. Select the ***Text Flow*** tab
3. Check **Insert** in the ***Breaks*** section
4. Select **Page** for *Type*
5. Select **Before** for *Position*
6. Click OK

Each **`Heading 1`** will now have a page break inserted just before.